# Excel RANK function with varing RANGE

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Is it possible to force Excel to only use populated cells for the RANK function?

Without using VBA

Comment: Can you post an example where RANK() is returning an unwanted value because of blank/non-numerical cells?  I'm not seeing such behavior in my tests.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you can use an `IF` function to "filter out" blanks. For example to rank data in `A2:A10` which might contain blanks, use this formula in B2 copied down

`=IF(A2="","",RANK(A2,A$2:A$10))`

Comment: This solution is simpler than the other suggested solution, though both work _in this instance_

Answer (score 1):

Excel sure has a lot of functions.. I think

```
=IF(ISERROR(RANK(B12,$B$1:$B$20)),"",RANK(B12,$B$1:$B$20))
```

is the correct formula for that. See [Ranking in Excel Tutorial](http://pinoytechnoguide.blogspot.com/2012/04/ranking-in-excel.html#more).

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you don't want to see the #N/A. You will have to do error checking. Something like this will work (it's not elegant because it requires excel to run the function twice if it isn't blank):

```
=IF(ISERROR(RANK(B12,$B$1:$B$20)),"",RANK(B12,$B$1:$B$20))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:
`=IF(A1<>"", RANK(A1, $A$1:$A$10),"")`
The difference between this and the highest ranked answer is this operates on a `true` whereas the other solution relies on a `false` to operate. Neither is necessarily better *in this case*